# Why irradiated color CMOS sensor shows white (not color) dots?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, radiation, radioactivity

I exposed CMOS imaging sensor (OmniVision OV2710) to radiation from Radium watch dial, through 2 glass layers (test tube + IR-cut filter, so all low energy particles were filtered out).

On the image that was captured over 2 minutes - there are some dots and lines caused by radiation which is expected. But they all white. Is there any explanation why they are white?

I expected that particles hitting R,G,B subpixels should cause color noise. Pixels are not clipped - some marks are far from 255 value. Also, I noticed that dots are typically larger than 1 pixel - does that mean that interaction volume is larger than 3x3µm (pixel size of OV2710)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I assume that your low energy filtering is also eliminating visible light, so you're only detecting gamma (& maybe some beta). I also assume that the watch is fairly old, so it contains a mixture of daughter isotopes, not just Ra-226.

Comment: @PM2Ring Dial is indeed very old, so luminophore had degraded completely and does not glow. But radiation is still there, and surely it is daughter products. I also measured gamma spectrum, which matches expectations.

Comment: Ra-226 has a half-life of 1600 years, so there's still plenty of it left. I hope you're taking appropriate precautions to avoid breathing the radon-222 it's producing...

Comment: A Radium gamma has a lot of energy.  It seems reasonable to me that keV deposited in one pixel would cause significant bleeding into adjacent pixels.  Just a guess.